# Set Ratings dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using this java script library to show ratings http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Overview. I'm using below method to set the ranks When page loads.

```
<input name='star_1' type='radio' value='1' class='star'/>
<input name='star_1' type='radio' value='2' class='star'/>
<input name='star_1' type='radio' value='3' class='star'/>
<input name='star_1' type='radio' value='4' class='star'/>
<input name='star_1' type='radio' value='5' class='star'/>
```

---

```
  $('.levelBucket li .star').rating({
        required: true,
        callback: function (value, link) {  }
    });
```

This works fine when user clicks on stars but i want to set rating with out user click. There is a separate event and at the end of that event i want to change rating by Java script. How can i do that ?

Comment: Initially I call above method to set ratings. Then again i want set change the rating based on another event. When I checked DOM elements those have been changed in following way                       

<DIV class="star-rating rater-18 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live star-rating-on" jQuery15108890803143774091="346"><A title=1>1</A></DIV>
<INPUT style="DISPLAY: none" class="star star-rating-applied" name=star_8b4e93a2-56b0-e111-8df0-00155d01ab06 value=1 type=radio jQuery15108890803143774091="347">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.levelBucket li .star').rating('select', value);
```

Also see [the API](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-API).

=== UPDATE ===

add to the html:

```
<button id="set-rating">set rating</button>
```

add to the javascript:

```
$('#set-rating').click(function() {
    $('.star').rating('select', '3');
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/vF44k/).

Comment: Please check the comment in the question.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you want to do something in the callback, I think you have to change the classname *star* in the html and js selector (don't ask me why / also see this [test](http://jsfiddle.net/7AhBt/2/)). Otherwise if you want to do something if another event is triggered, please tell us more about this event.

Comment: I want to change the Rating when another event triggered. Event is just a button click in a popup and i have to get the new rating value and set it on existing star rating.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **[API](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-API)**

If your rating system looks like
`Example: (values A/B/C/D/E)`

```
By Index: $('input').rating('select',3) 
By Value: $('input').rating('select','C')
```

In your case, it should be something like this

`$('.levelBucket li .star').rating('select', your-value);`

Hope this helps

Comment: Please check the comment in the question.